# Install service without root privileges using Install4J

Tags: install4j

In MacOS, if I add "request privilege" action before "install service" action, install4j creates a plist file under /Library/LaunchDaemons/ directory. I'm trying to install service as a non-root user which doesn't request privileges and want this plist file to be created under ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ directory. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 7.x, this is not possible. It is planned to support user-specific LaunchAgents in 8.0.

Comment: I see. Thanks @Ingo for clarifying. What about windows? Is it possible to run a service as a non-administrator user in windows using install4j 7.x?

Comment: I tried LocalService in "Install a service" action for windows without "Request privileges" and it fails with ServiceException{errorCode:5000}. Does this mean it's not possible to run a service in windows as a non-administrator?

Comment: Indeed, it is generally not possible to run a service as a non-admin user on Windows.

Comment: I see. @Ingo can you recommend how install4j based installer can be run in unattended mode and have a service installed in windows?

Comment: Or is it possible that I install a service after requesting privileges and then an update runs in unattended mode which stops and restarts the service without requesting privileges?

Comment: I was able to run the service as "other" Account and the service gets installed and runs as provided user. But still when the installer runs again without "request privileges" it's not able to stop and start service (Access Denied). The command "net stop <service-name>" also says Access Denied.

Comment: You need elevated privileges to modify services, there is no way around that. You could run the updater from a service that already has elevated privileges.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Ingo

Comment: @IngoKegel Is this possible now?

Comment: No, sorry, this has not been implemented yet.